# Convert index of a dataframe from yyyy-mm-dd to yyyy-mm

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe with index in the `yyyy-mm-dd` format and I want to make it `yyyy-mm` only.
Can you please help? HHC

Answer (score 0):

Use `strftime` as follows:

```
from datetime import date
import pandas as pd
td = date.today()

datelist = pd.date_range(td, periods=100).tolist()
d = {'data': list(range(10)),
     'index': pd.date_range(td, periods=10).tolist()}
df = pd.DataFrame(d).set_index('index')
display(df)
df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.index)
df.index = df.index.strftime("%Y %m")
df.head()
```

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 possibilities:

If your index contains date as string:

```
df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.index).to_period('M')

# OR

df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.index).strftime('%Y-%m')
```

If your index is already a `DatetimeIndex`, you can just do:

```
df.index = df.index.to_period('M')

# OR

df.index = df.index.strftime('%Y-%m')
```

Example:

```
>>> df
            col
2023-01-01    1
2023-02-01    2
2023-03-01    3
2023-04-01    4

# df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.index).to_period('M')
>>> df.index
PeriodIndex(['2023-01', '2023-02', '2023-03', '2023-04'], dtype='period[M]')

# df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.index).strftime('%Y-%m')
>>> Index(['2023-01', '2023-02', '2023-03', '2023-04'], dtype='object')
```

[`PeriodIndex`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.PeriodIndex.html) is more useful if you want to deal with some date operations.

To know every format codes for `strftime`, refer to the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-format-codes)

Comment: @HnV. Did one answer solved your problem?

Answer (score 0):

```py
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime
import numpy as np

# Generate dates
date_rng = pd.date_range(start='1/1/2023', end='1/08/2024', freq='D')

# Create Pandas dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame(date_rng, columns=['date'])

# Add column with random numbers as number as records we generated
df['data'] = np.random.randint(0,100,size=(len(date_rng)))
#display(df)

# Convert the data frame index to a datetime index
df['datetime'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])
df = df.set_index('datetime')
# delete\drop date column
df.drop(['date'], axis=1, inplace=True)
#df.head()

#=====================> Approach#1 <======================
# Manipulate index to convert yyyy-mm-dd to yyyy-mm format
df.index = df.index.strftime("%Y-%m")
#=====================> Approach#2 <======================
# Manipulate index to convert yyyy-mm-dd to yyyy-mm format 
#df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.index).strftime('%Y-%m')
print(df)
```

---

Output:

```
#datetime      
#2023-01     89
#2023-01     10
#2023-01     29
#2023-01     54
#2023-01     73
#...        ...
#2024-01     93
#2024-01     97
#2024-01     85
#2024-01     36
#2024-01     80
```

References:

- [Basic Time Series Manipulation with Pandas](https://towardsdatascience.com/basic-time-series-manipulation-with-pandas-4432afee64ea)